# Casting UIViewcontroller, ends up as

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a custom class that inherits from UIViewController and when I want to navigate I am casting a seque to this class like this

```
MyCustomViewController *vc =  ((MyCustomViewController *)segue.destinationViewController);
```

And that works but if I look in Xcode the vc variable is really a UINavigationController (which I think is my root problem).
And then I next try to set some variables on that view and get an exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController
>   setMyVarID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbe59ec0'

This is all storyboard ios views which I have not dealt with at all before but am trying to chase down a bug in code that is already done.

Any ideas on how to get that cast working correctly or what else I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide a screen shot of your StoryBoard setup that would be helpful in determining what the exact questions is.

Consider this setup:

VC1 -> Modal Segue -> NAV1 -> Root View Relationship -> VC2

If the Navigation Controller (NAV1) has a Root View relationship to a View Controller (VC2) and you have a segue form VC1 to NAV1, then in the prepareForSegue: method, your destination view controller isn't the NAV1 but instead is the Root View (VC2).

So you need to assign the class to the VC2 (UserWishListRoomsViewController) instead of the NAV1 (it should be a generic UINavigationController) and then the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C will let you cast an `id` to anything.  You need to cast it to `UINavigationController` and probably get the `topViewController` for it.